# How to map correctly two arrays with booleans

Tags: angular, typescript, mapping

I have a list `accounts`. I also have a list `accountsWithSelectedField` which I mapped like this:

```
this.accountsWithSelectedField = this.accounts.map(s => ({...s, selected: false}));
```

Now from an http request I receive a list of `accountsSetups` (accounts that were selected). I should map everything accordingly. Basically it should look like this:

```
accounts: 111, 222, 333, 444
accountsWithSelectedField: {111: false}, {222: false}, {333: false}, {444: false}
accountSetups(from http): {222, true, true}, {333, true, false}
After mapping => accountsWithSelectedField: {111: false}, {222: true}, {333: true}, {444: false}
```

I need help figuring out how to map it correctly, I tried doing it like this, but there are some issues, either the iban is not showing, or everything is mapped as a true.

```
this.accountsWithSelectedField = this.accounts.map(o => data.accountSetups.map(s => ({
       iban: o.iban,
       selected: s.someBoolean || s.anotherBoolean
     })));
```

Also tried like this:

```
for (const account of this.accountsWithSelectedField) {
      for (const acc of data.accountSetups) {
        if (account.iban === acc.account.iban) {
          console.log(account.iban + ' is true');
          account.selected = true;
        }
      }
    }
```

And I got 3 out of six ibans `is true`(correct), but all six of them were selected, I can't understand why?

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like that:

```
const accounts = [111, 222, 333, 444];
const accountsWithSelectedField
  = accounts.map(account => ({id: account, someBoolean: false}));
const accountSetups = [
  {id: 222, someBoolean: true, anotherBoolean: true, iban: '123'},
  {id: 333, someBoolean: true, anotherBoolean: false, iban: '456'}
];

for (const accountSetup of accountSetups) {
  const associatedAccount = accountsWithSelectedField.find(account => account.id === accountSetup.id);
  if (associatedAccount) {
    associatedAccount.someBoolean = accountSetup.someBoolean || accountSetup.anotherBoolean;
  }
}
```